# FusionCharts : Custom Scale (letters instead of numbers)

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

Please, I need help with scale in FusionCharts.

Instead of (0$, 20$ ...) I want : A B C D where each letter has a significant value (A = 1, B = 2 , ...).

The people at the support told me that it's not supported natively. And I could do it with trendlines.

Anyone has tried with trendlines or any other solution ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution, I've tried with annotations but it did'nt work for me because I was using a multi series bar chart.
So I've finally gone with Trendlines :

```
"trendlines": [
    {
     "line": [
             {
                "startvalue": "1",
                "endvalue": "1",
                "color": "#111111",
                "displayvalue": "A",
                "dashed": "0",
                "thickness": "0",
                "dashgap": "6",
                "alpha": "100",
                "showontop": "1"
             },
             {
                "startvalue": "2",
                "endvalue": "2",
                "color": "#111111",
                "displayvalue": "B",
                "dashed": "0",
                "thickness": "0",
                "dashgap": "6",
                "alpha": "100",
                "showontop": "1"
             }
     ]
    }
```

]

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [annotation](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/advanced-chart-configurations/annotations/introduction.html) feature. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/S84S8/) which should help you to achieve what you want.

Hide the yAxis by

```
"showYAxisValues": "0",
```

Then create the axis through annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll try and give a feedback

Comment: It's working but the problem I'm facing is that the anotations stay fixed, I want it to change depending on the width of the chart